# Global Variable Not Update ( Swift )

Tags: ios, swift

I have a global variable, but when I give the value of the variable does not change when I 
run in `viewDidload`, this is my code :

(https://pastebin.com/7QbBjLNC)

Comment: You will saw its new value if you check your variable value `fetchData( .. )`

Comment: Your code snippet should be part of the question and not linked to other site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is being fetched asynchronously and the print statement is getting executed before the response is received. print the data after you assign value to self.jumlahStok